# DatagridColumn CheckBox Bound Checked property not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have a Datagrid with Bound Columns to a List(Of AnonymouseType), one is a CheckBox using DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate, this is the XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgServicios" Margin="15" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                  AlternatingRowBackground="#CCEEF6"  
                                  SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" TabIndex="20" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Selected" Width="Auto">                            
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="CheckBox_Click"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Codigo" Binding="{Binding Codigo}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" Binding="{Binding Nombre}" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

The CheckBox works fine at runtime but the IsChecked property doesn't persist when I try to recover values from DB, the items Boolean property is ok, but none of Bound Checkboxes are checked. How Can I get the Checkboxes match with the items boolean property?? The Binding is wrong?

Comment: We will need to see how your ViewModel works. For value change to get propogated to view, the property must raise a notification change. Not sure if that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide more information on the list of objects you are binding to?

From what I can tell, your bindings appear to be coded correctly. I tried copying and pasting your xaml into a new solution and then set the ItemsSource property it to an class I created that has your same column names, and everything appears to work correctly. The ObservableCollection of "GridItem" I'm bound to implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and anytime a property gets updated, it notifies the UI. This is what I did to test out your xaml:

The code behind for MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<GridItem> GridItems;    

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GridItems = new ObservableCollection<GridItem>();

            GridItems.Add(new GridItem { Codigo = "value1", Nombre = "Value2", Selected = false });
            GridItems.Add(new GridItem { Codigo = "value3", Nombre = "Value4", Selected = true });
            GridItems.Add(new GridItem { Codigo = "value5", Nombre = "Value6", Selected = false });

            dgServicios.ItemsSource = GridItems;
        }

        private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }


    public class GridItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _Selected;

        public bool Selected
        {
            get { return _Selected; }
            set 
            { 
                _Selected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        private string _Codigo;

        public string Codigo
        {
            get { return _Codigo; }
            set
            {
                _Codigo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private string _Nombre;

        public string Nombre
        {
            get { return _Nombre; }
            set
            {
                _Nombre = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

If you provide more specific info on this, I might be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I found I mistake de Binding Path, correct property was "Seleccionado" (In Spanish) and I wrote Selected (n english :P ) ... Thank you any way :)

Comment: Ah, good one. That was actually going to be one of my next questions about spelling and binding names. FYI, in the future, you can go to the "Project Output" window in Visual Studio to see if you have any warning about binding errors, since by default, they don't cause any compile errors.